# tcpdump on any interface does not support VLAN

Tags: vlan, tcpdump, java

I have tried the following command: tcpdump -i any vlan , on both Ubuntu 10.04 (kernel 2.6.32-36) and Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 3.8.0-39) and got the following output: tcpdump: no VLAN support for data link type 113 . tcpdump/libpcap versions are 4.2.1/1.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 and 4.0.0/1.0.0 on Ubuntu 10.04. Do you know if this is an inherent inability of tcpdump? Is there any alternative in order to filter on the any interface and specific vlan(s)?

Thank you.

Comment: might this help? a bugreport on your error message:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=558209

Comment: The bug report above could be related but I am not sure, since it concerns tcpflow.